# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error

Tags: java, android

I am getting a blank screen when app launches and when i check log i get:
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error

I cannot figure out why? Any ideas, it does not seem to be attaching the recyclerView or adding any Data, I have attached the Main activity, DataAdapter and data classes.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://demo3317540.mockable.io";


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Included> data;
    private Adapter adapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data = new ArrayList<>();

        initViews();
        loadJSON();

    }

    private void initViews() {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

    private void loadJSON() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JsonResponse> call = request.getYesterData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonResponse> call, Response<JsonResponse> response) {

                JsonResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getIncluded()));
                adapter = new Adapter(data);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



            }
```

**Data Adapter**

```
 public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>{

        private List<Included> includedData;


        public Adapter(List<Included> includedData) {
            this.includedData = includedData;

        }


        @Override
        public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


            holder.tvCompetitionName.setText(includedData.get(position).getAttributes().getName());
            holder.homeTeam.setText(includedData.get(position).getRelationships().getCompetition().getData().getType());



            holder.itemView.setTag(includedData.get(position));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return includedData.size();

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private TextView tvCompetitionName;
            private TextView homeTeam;
            private TextView score;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                tvCompetitionName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.competitionNameTV);
                homeTeam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeTeamTv);
                score = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.score);
            }
        }
}
```

Below is my data class where data will be getting pulled from

Included.java

```
public class Included implements Serializable, Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("relationships")
    @Expose
    private Relationships relationships;
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private Attributes attributes;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

}
```

**Getters and setters**

and this is the jsonResponse class, which is referenced in the Interface

```
public class JsonResponse {

    private Included[] included;

    public Included[] getIncluded() {
        return included;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your adapter and call recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: I do call it if you check main activity it is called there

Comment: You need to initialize it synchronously along with your other RecyclerView initialization. Set an empty adapter as a variable of the class and add it to the RecyclerView, then add the data afterwards (when your network request returns a response).